# How to use angular variable in <a> tag

Tags: html, angular

In my component I subscribe some basic data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getBasics().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.basics = data
      }
    )
  }
```

I use them in html like this:

```
<h1>{{ basics.surname }}</h1>
```

and it works perfectly fine. A few of basics are the links. Assume basics.mypage to be "http://mypage.com". I would like to use it as a href in my html document. Something like this:

```
<a href={{ basics.mypage }}>Go to my page</a>
```

but that way it sends me to

> http://localhost:4200/%7Bbasics.mypage%7D

How to use this variable inside  tag?

Comment: You can use [attr.href]="basics.mypage"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just insert {{basics.mypage}} into quotes

```
<a href="{{basics.mypage}}">Go to my page</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref):

```
<a ng-href={{ basics.mypage }}>Go to my page</a>
```

or check that the data is properly formatted.

Comment: He's asking about Angular, not AngularJS !

Answer (score 1):

Another way is also available thats called property binding.

```
<a [href]="variableName"></a>

or

<a [attr.href]="variableName"></a>
```

Comment: We could say [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) and [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding).

Answer (score 1):

Always prepend your absolute external links with protocol or // shortcut for http:// OR https:// depending on your app's protocol.

```
<div class="inline-icon-text">
<small class="text-muted d-md-none mr-3">Link</small>
 <a [attr.href]="'//' + candidate.url" target="_blank" [title]="candidate.url">
<i class="material-icons">open_in_new</i>
 </a>
</div>
```

Browsers treat URLs as a relative by default to facilitate in-app navigation.

As a side note, this behavior is not Angular-specific; other frameworks and plain sites behave exactly the same.
This also a great way of doing that.

Comment: problem was not with lack of http:// but with lack of "" around {{ basics.mypage }}. But thank you for your time!